# Why does even a 16-byte aligned address cause _mm_load_si128 to cause access violation?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

The following compiles without warnings on MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() 
{
    __declspec(align(16)) int x = 42;
    std::cout << &x << "\n";  // Print out the address that holds x

    __m128i v = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(x));
}
```

Essentially, the code aligns a 32-bit integer, and tries to load that into a __m128i type. The [`_mm_load_si128`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atzzad1h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) *requires* the input address to be 16-byte aligned. The [`_mm_loadu_si128`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4k12ae8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does not require it, but both cause the above code to emit an access violation when ran. Why, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgotten to take the address of `x`:

```
__m128i v = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(&x));
//                                          ^
//                                          |
//                     Here ----------------+
```

In addition, you did not provide enough space for the data, so `_mm_load_si128` would end up reading past the end of the allocated block of memory.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that a 16 byte load is inappropriate for an int.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for a great comment - I missed the undefined behavior there!

Comment: @user3475799 According to the spec, 16-byte alignment should be enough.

Comment: @user3475799 All you need is allocating sufficient space for your `x` variable. You can make it a an array of four 32-bit `int`s, like this: `int x[4];` Note that now you need to remove the ampersand, because `x` is an array, so its name would be interpreted like a pointer in an expression.